# How to play two songs on two speakers separately?

Tags: audio

I've noticed quite a lot of people asking how to play two songs on speakers and headphone. My question is how to play two songs on two speakers separately on OS X or Windows XP? (one song on left speaker and the other song on right speaker) I need this technique to demonstrate destructive sound waves. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to load both songs into [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/), and use the Pan slider to set one to the left channel, and the other to the right channel.

[image]

Comment: Yeah @Huskehn has got a good point, since you mentioned you would like to demonstrate destructive sound waves. And it's priceless.

Answer (score 3):

You can use two different music players one playing only in left and other playing only in right.

Example in Winamp...

[image: Audio control]

Comment: Do you know a music player that can play the music only on the left or only on the right side? Setting the balance in Windows won't work since it sets the balance for all audio output.

Comment: WinAmp is one...

Comment: You may try Winamp on a Stick, and you can run two of them next to eachother. I don't know if this works (no Windows here), but it's worth a try.

Comment: But can you run two instance of winamp??